How does the rotor of a hybrid stepper motor move from one phase to the next, given the instability at equilibrium?
Given:

I am working with a two-phase hybrid stepper motor. The rotor has 50
pole pairs, and the stator consists of 8 poleshoes, each with 6
teeth, for a total of 48 teeth. I have drawn the stepper motor in LaTeX using TikZ to better illustrate its operation.
In Image(1) below, the motor is in its initial position. Poleshoes A
are magnetized as a south pole, and A/ as a north pole. Poleshoes B
and B/ are not magnetized.
In Image(2), the magnetic field has rotated by 45° counterclockwise.
Now, poleshoes B/ are magnetized as a south pole, and B as a north
pole, while A and A/ are not magnetized. As a result, the rotor's
magnetic field has rotated by 1.8° counterclockwise.

Image(1):

Image(2):

Questions:

What ensures the rotor moves in the correct direction (i.e.,
counterclockwise by 1.8°) when transitioning between these two
phases? How is this 50/50 equilibrium resolved in the stepper motor's
operation? Image(3) below provides a detailed view of the rotor in
the position shown in Image(1), where this unstable equilibrium is
evident.
Additionally, could someone please verify whether the stator teeth
are accurately represented in my drawings? I am concerned that their
positions may differ from those in a real stepper motor.

Image(3):

Answer: (thanks to DaveTweed)
There is no unstable equilibrium state as it is shown in Image(3).

Where's the metastability? In your last diagram, if B/ becomes a north pole, the rotor will rotate clockwise, and if it becomes a south pole, the rotor will rotate counterclockwise.


BTW, I'm impressed with your TikZ skills. I need to learn how to do that. I'll change my comment into an answer so that you can accept it.

Thank you so much! I’m not an expert, but I can certainly show you the basics in TikZ. I’d love for you to teach me VHDL in return! Have a great day!

Where's the metastability? In your last diagram, if B/ becomes a north pole, the rotor will rotate clockwise, and if it becomes a south pole, the rotor will rotate counterclockwise.

Oh my goodness! I’ve spent three hours crafting this question, and now I see it clearly. You’re absolutely right—it is correct and it works. There is no metastability. THX a lot
